# Search for Minimum Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, subquery

Support user selected 10 columns to search from screen in ASP.NET

We need to search minimum 8 columns matching in database

How to write sql query for matching any 8 columns out of 10

We need to match ONLY 8 Matching columns out of 10

Comment: Please provide some data samples and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an **expression** which shows how many columns matched, then compare it to the number of columns which need to match.

Something like this:

```
where
-- How many columns matched? 
-- Score 1 for each matching column
0
+ case when column1 = @search1 then 1 else 0 end
+ case when column2 = @search2 then 1 else 0 end
+ case when column3 = @search3 then 1 else 0 end
+ case when column4 = @search4 then 1 else 0 end
+ case when column5 = @search5 then 1 else 0 end
+ case when column6 = @search6 then 1 else 0 end
+ case when column7 = @search7 then 1 else 0 end
+ case when column8 = @search8 then 1 else 0 end
+ case when column9 = @search9 then 1 else 0 end
+ case when column10 = @search10 then 1 else 0 end

>= 8
```

You can generalize this approach to giving different scores for different columns.

Note that this approach will not use indexes on any of the search columns.

However if several of the columns have indexes, you can likely improve the performance by using them. (To match eight out of ten columns, using indexes, at least three columns would have to have an index).

Comment: your query brings data for individual columns matched
query must match any 8 columns out of 10 query
one possible solution i came across is 
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Column1=Value1 AND Columns2 =Value2 .... till 8 columns 
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Column2=Value1 AND Columns3 =Value2 .... till 8 columns

Comment: @samdubey the example above creates a "score" where each matching column adds 1 to the score. Then it checks if the score is 8 or above. Your suggestion requires choose 8 out of 10 combinations = 90 separate select queries.

Comment: query works fine for columns with = operator in search.
how about like operator in search query?

Comment: I think i need to write CASE WHEN EXISTS ( Search condition) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END